# Text formatting is not showing in sent mail using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

The body of email is a dynamically created web page using **HttpWebRequest.create()**. This 
page is well formatted but not showing the formatting applied (bold effect,
color of font, size of font etc) when I open the email in my account.
Is it a normal behaviour of this mechanism or **is there
any way to receive well formatted email from asp.net** ?

Comment: how you are formatting text in mail. If you can post that code that will be helpful...

Comment: hey @Mayank Pathak I think i solved that issue. I was using css classes for formatting the data that was the snag so why i could not saw any formatting to data in email. Then i formatted each data item individually and it worked...

Comment: Good and Congrats...let us know any other issues you face..